# JavaFX 2 WebView URL Listener

Tags: java, javafx-2

When using a JavaFX (2.2) WebView, is there a way to listen to and handle url's within java code?

For example: I'm loading a local HTML file to my WebView with webEngine.loadContent(html). The HTML contains resources like

```
<script src="local:my-script.js"></script>
<img src="cms:1234.png"/>
```

which is also a local file and should be provided from the java application. So I want to register a listener that could handle requests from the page.

Edit: The resource data that is loaded within the HTML page comes from a content-managemant-system so using relative paths is not working.

Comment: There is a easy way I think: Make all Ressources relative to you HTML-file and load that file local by file:///folder/file.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own URL protocol handler and install it using:

```
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new HandlerFactory());
```

[A New Era for Java URL Protocol Handlers article](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_protocolHandlers/java_protocol.pdf) provides detailed instructions for creating the handler.

WebView can make use of your custom protocol to load your content.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you would be substituting `local:` resource with runtime value in html right before loading it. E.g.:

```
public class WebViewLocal extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String st = "<html><head><title>X</title>"
                + "</head><body><img src='local:1.jpg'/>"
                + "</body></html>";
        System.out.println(st);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loadHtml(st), 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public WebView loadHtml(String html) {
        html = html.replace("local:", getClass().getResource(".").toString());
        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.getEngine().loadContent(html);
        return view;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

N.B.: This is working sample, just put `1.jpg` image at the same place as this file.

If you *really* want to work with java class from javascript you can use "JavaFX to JavaScript bridge" feature. Take a look at tutorial here: https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

Comment: Thank you. But I think this will not work for e.g. images like <img src="local:my_img.png"/>. For any text-value (script, css, ...) it could work.

Comment: This anser will not help in this case: With loadContent() will only load a content (the browsers location), but the question is about loading a dependent ressource.

Comment: @chrise: it will work for any resource which use urls including images

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: `loadContent(string)` loads html content from string value. `load(url)` loads content from URL. @chrise in his question asked about former method.

Comment: I've extended code snippet a bit to demonstrate full working example.

Comment: Maybe my question was a bit confusing. I don't only want to replace the "local" String with any other path. I want the data e.g. bytes of an image to be send to the browser when it requests it. Like working as a pseudo-http-server.

Comment: use a real server then, e.g. there is very convenient java server Jetty: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

Answer (score 0):

If you load your html-file locally, you can simply use relative paths:

This is an example, which load html, with relative scripts.
http://code.google.com/p/jfx-gap/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jfxgap/JFXGap.java

The trick schould be the relative path inside the html.

Comment: Yes right, this will work with local files. I forgot to mention that the data comes from a content-management-system so more business-logic is required. One idea I had was, running a small http-server to provide the data and rewrite all paths in the HTML but maybe there's a smarter solution for that.